# At what point does a piece of code become a virus and at what point does this become illegal?

Tags: virus

I read a lot about viruses being illegal, but at what point does a piece of code become a virus and become illegal? Information enters and leaves our computers on a daily basis and often times some information from our computer will enter someone elses computer in some form via the internet. Is there a legal definition of a virus and what is considered to be illegal? Is it only when the virus steals information of causes some malicious harm that it is illegal?

Comment: Legality would depend on country/region and would vary. If there are legal concerns, you should ask a lawyer. A virus is a self replicating code; if this code is not authorized to be run on a system this may be a problem, but running code on your own server may not.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the law in an unspecified locale.